# Related post not showing table of content

Tags: posts, themes, templates, excerpt, content

I have squaretype themes and this themes use built in table of content. My question is how to change related post to show excerpt not table of content words?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem solved already. i have to add a word to the excerpt box on the right area on gutenberg editor.